# Inequality for solutions a solution of system of quadratic equations.

Tags: inequality, dynamical-systems, quadratics, game-theory, implicit-function

> Let $v_{i,j}\in [0,1], i,j = 0,\ldots,n$ solve the following system of equations for $r>0$:
> \begin{align} 
>   0 &= \tfrac 1 2 e_{i,j}^2 + e_{j,i} v_{i,j+1} - (r+e_{j,i}) v_{i,j}, \tag{*} \\
>   e_{i,j} &= v_{i+1,j}-v_{i,j}, \\
>   v_{n,j} &= 1, \\
>   v_{i,n} &= 0,
> \end{align}
> for $i,j = 0,\ldots,n-1$.

**Claim:**

- a) for fixed $i\in \{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ the function $j\mapsto e_{i,j}$  is increasing for $j\leq i$ and decreasing for $j\geq i$.
- b) for fixed $j\in \{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ the function $i\mapsto e_{i,j}$ is increasing.

Specifically, in case of $n=2$, we want to prove that $e_{0,1} < e_{0,0} < e_{1,0} < e_{1,1}$.

**Interpretation:** These equations represent the competition in a [patent race](https://academic.oup.com/restud/article-abstract/54/1/1/1582628): Two players compete for a patent. It takes $n$ discoveries to be able to patent, the player that patents first wins the race (reward 1), whist the other loses (reward 0). A player with $i$ discoveries knowing that his rival has made $j$ discoveries makes effort $e_{i,j}\geq 0$, which translates into the hazard rate $e_{i,j}$ of making the next discovery, and cost flow $\tfrac 1 2 (e_{i,j})^2$. The time is continuous and future payoffs are discounted at the rate $r>0$. Continuation value $v_{i,j}$ is the expected discounted future payoff flow (probability of winning minus the integral of effort cost over time). The claim is that: Players exert higher effort when being neck and neck; having a lead or lagging discourages effort.

The problem has been intensely studied by economist since the 80', but most studies consider a general convex effort cost function, whist the equations (*) are obtained under a more restrictive assumption of quadratic effort cost functions. In the general case the monotonicity of $v_{i,j}$ does not necessarily hold. (Cf. [Grossman and Shapiro (1987)](https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w1674/w1674.pdf))

I have solved the problem for $n=2$, but it is a several page long proof that is very technical (I find upper and lower boundary on the variables step by step, there is not much intuiting behind it).

Comment: You first say "Show that $v_{i,j}$ is increasing in $i$ and decreasing in $j$" and later "The claim is [...] $e_{i,j}$ is increasing in $i$, [...] $e_{i,j}$ is decreasing in $j$". Which one is it?

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks a lot for pointing it out, I corrected it. The monotonicity of $v_{i,j}$ (increasing in $i$ and decreasing in $j$) holds too and it is relatively easy to show it, difficult is to obtain the result comparing the efforts.

Comment: Can you recommend me a way to get more attention to this question (despite its difficulty)?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty

Comment: Hi Anne, I'm thinking about the bounty, I actually spent last three days answering questions to gain necessary reputation for that. However, I want to make sure that my question is well presented before offering a bounty. What makes me wonder is that I asked several questions carefully - explaining the motivation and my research on the problem. However, despite my effort, I got neither answers, comments, or up votes (except for the one up vote here) - unlike other poorly stated on the network. I don't expect to see solutions since my questions are hard, but comments or votes a lest?